# Create a dataframe from many objects' attributes

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a Point class with attributes like 'easting', 'northing', 'elevation', 'color', 'code', etc.
Right now I'm iterating over a generator of thousands of these Points to draw them in pygame to graph them. During this process I need to convert the 'easting' and 'northing' values into pixel coordinates for display. To speed up both the conversion and the drawing, I want to try using pandas.

My idea so far is to create a dataframe with each column being an attribute and each row being a point. What is the best way to do this for performance?
And if you have other ideas for approaching this, please let me know.

Comment: you are going to have to just iterate over your points and create a list-of-lists, maybe some list-comprehension `pd.DataFrame([[p.easting, p.northing] for p in points_generator])`. That won't be particularly performant, but if you only have something on the order of thousands of points, it should be fast enough. Note sure how your data-frame will fare for your actual use-case though. In any event, you'll need to provide some sort of approach and ideally some benchmakrs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It sounds like the dataframe construction won't be my bottleneck so I should focus on something else. Thanks!